# How to make sure rendering from one GL program overlays rendering from other program?

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d

I am working in Android Studio With Open GL ES 2.0.

Every time I render the view I use two GL programs. They have different shaders.
Now It happens that the objects I draw in the programs overlap. My problem is now that when they overlap the Object that I want to be behind the other is on top. What I want is basically that the object which is drawn by program2 is always visible while the other object is like in the background and when they overlap it is behind the other.

How can I make sure of that? I can´t disable the depth test because the objects I draw require it.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL doesn't care about your object structure. Since it only deals with triangles,  everything will be depth-tested when enabled.

The only thing that comes to my mind is to render both objects to separate fbos (with depth-test enabled) and then combine them (without depth testing) in the order you want the objects to be. Be aware, that this will not scale very well when you have a lot of this objects.

Answer (score 0):

The program has nothing to do with it. But on the basic problem of rendering two objects, with proper depth testing within each object, but one object completely in front of the other, there are at least two easy approaches.

#### Clear Depth Buffer Twice

One approach is that you render the background object first, then clear the depth buffer, then render the foreground object:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
// Draw first ("background") object.
glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
// Draw second ("foreground") object.
```

Note that only the depth buffer is cleared with the second `glClear()` call. So both objects will be displayed. But since you clear the depth buffer before drawing the second object, the first object will not obscure the second object.

#### Use Depth Range

Another approach is that you use a different depth range for each object. By default, the depth range is [0.0, 1.0], meaning that the visible depth range is mapped to the full range of depth values. But you can change this. For your example:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glDepthRangef(0.5f, 1.0f);
// Draw first ("background") object.
glDepthRangef(0.0f, 0.5f);
// Draw second ("foreground") object.
glDepthRange(0.0f, 1.0f);
```

The two objects are now mapped to different sub-ranges of the entire depth range. The first object will be mapped to depth values between 0.5 and 1.0, while the second object is mapped to depth values between 0.0 and 0.5. Therefore, all depth values of the second object will be smaller than the depth values of the first object, meaning that the depth test will consider the second object to be completely in front of the first object.

Answer (score 0):

Although there are may ways to achieve this result (2 are already posted) I would say this is a job for stencil buffer.

The rendering that has a priority (will always be in front) must also draw to the stencil buffer. The other programs must then discard the fragments where the stencil buffer has been drawn to using stencil tests.

The stencil buffer is much like a depth buffer but is not actually bound to the depth (the z value of the fragment). You may set the same tests as for the depth buffer and as I've seen some implementations you may even use it on the same buffer as depth so you have 24bits for depth and 8 for stencil. So for 8 bit stencil buffer you would be able to actually use 256 drawing procedures which are then prioritized one before another.

So you have no depth precision loss by changing the depth range nor any performance issues as would be with using multiple FBOs and then merging them together.